# Bios passwords "easy" to find

Tags: bios

I have read that bios passwords are sometimes good--or bad, if there is a default. Places mention that these passwords are pretty much just available through google, but I can not find them.

Where would I find them?

Answer (score 2):

A list of BIOS passwords is [here](http://www.uktsupport.co.uk/reference/biosp.htm). Note that while BIOS passwords help to protect to a certain extent, they are no barrier when someone has gained control over a computer. They could use utilities like [flashrom](http://flashrom.org/Flashrom) to change the password, or even embed a rootkit into the BIOS flash chip.

Comment: Many times manufacturers also embed a BIOS password reset jumper onto the motherboard. So if someone knows which pins to connect that's another way to reset the password without knowing it. Obviously not very stealthy, but it'll get you in if you have physical access to the motherboard.